# The difference between inList and listContains filter in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm working with filter in Google Earth Engine and I want to know what is the difference between these 2 filters:

- `ee.Filter.listContains(leftField, rightValue, rightField, leftValue)`
- `ee.Filter.inList(leftField, rightValue, rightField, leftValue)`

They use the same arguments, return the same results and when I call and print `ee.ListContains` filter I get `ee.inList`.

[demo](https://code.earthengine.google.com/d7b6ca541dbc7ea2fe6539191ed1cef9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apply `listContains()` on `List` properties. You check if the list propertycontains the value you provide. `inList()` works the other way around, where you provide a list and check if the property is contained in your list.

Here are some examples that might explain it:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD")
  .limit(1)

print('PROPERTIES', '----------')
print('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', collection.first().get('transmitterReceiverPolarisation'))
print('orbitProperties_pass', collection.first().get('orbitProperties_pass'))

print('FILTERED', '--------')
// listContains() on a List property.
// Valid use of this filter
print(collection
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'HH'))
  .aggregate_array('transmitterReceiverPolarisation')
)

// inList() on a List property where rightValue is a List of Strings.
// Invalid use of this filter, it will never match
print(collection
  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', ['HH']))
  .aggregate_array('transmitterReceiverPolarisation')
)
// inList() on a List property where rightValue is a List of Lists.
// Valid use of this filter.
print(collection
  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', [['HH', 'HV']]))
  .aggregate_array('transmitterReceiverPolarisation')
)

// listContains() on a String property.
// Invalid use of this filter, it gives an error
print(collection
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
  .aggregate_array('orbitProperties_pass')
)

// inList() on a String property where rightValue is a List of Strings
// Correct use of this filter
print(collection
  .filter(ee.Filter.inList('orbitProperties_pass', ['DESCENDING']))
  .aggregate_array('orbitProperties_pass')
)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/56fec740caf60d45b4e223df38067621